# issue Implementing DFS in java

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, nodes, depth-first-search

I am attempting to improve my grasp on learning to implement algorithms so I have begun to try to implement a Depth First Search in java. However, I am having trouble figuring out the proper way to create my Node class and create a tree structure with it. Could you give me a hand figuring out a better way to do it?

**Node Class**

```
public class Node<T>{
T data;
Node<T> parent;
ArrayList<Node<T>> children;

public Node(T data)
{
    this.data = data;
    this.children = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
}

public Node<T> addChild(T child)
{
    Node<T> childNode = new Node<T>(child);
    childNode.parent = this;
    this.children.add(childNode);
    return childNode;
}

public ArrayList<Node<T>> removeChild(T child)
{
    Node<T> childNode = new Node<T>(child);
    ArrayList<Node<T>> children = this.children;
    children.remove(child);
    return children;
}
}
```

**DepthFirstSearchClass**

```
public class DepthFirstSearch<T>{
public Node<T> root;
public Node<T> goal;
public Hashtable<Node<T>, Boolean> visited;

public boolean DepthFirstSearch(Node<T> root, Node<T> goal)
{
    this.root = root;
    this.goal = goal;

    if(this.root == this.goal)
    {
        System.out.println("The goal has been reached.");
        return true;

    } else {
        if(root.children.size()-1 >0)
        {
            for(Node<T>child: root.children)
            {
                DepthFirstSearch(child, goal);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
}
```

**Main**

```
public class Main{

public static Node<String> rootNode;
public static Node<String> childOne;
public static Node<String> childTwo;
public static Node<String> childThree;
public static DepthFirstSearch dfs;

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    //initializing variables
    rootNode = new Node<String>("rootNode");
    childOne = new Node<String>("childOne");
    childTwo = new Node<String>("childTwo");
    childThree = new Node<String>("childThree");
    dfs = new DepthFirstSearch();

    //building the trees
    rootNode.addChild(childOne);
    rootNode.addChild(childThree);
    childOne.addChild(childTwo);

    dfs.DepthFirstSearch(rootNode, childTwo);

}
}
```

Comment: one suggestion, you are using `this.root == this.goal` which is never true. Instead use equals method and overwrite it in Node class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following line from your code:
`if(root.children.size()-1 >0)`.

Firstly you are preventing to visit a single child and secondly `for(Node<T>child: root.children)` will skip iterating, if given node has no children.

Other than that, your DFS looks good.

Comment: Thanks for the help!